# How can I get getenv to work if $_ENV is working in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm running a PHP script via CLI.

var_dumping the `$_ENV['VARIABLE']` gives the expected value, but `getenv('VARIABLE')` does not.

I'm running a docker container php7.4.

How can I solve this?